# Is it possible to ignore Matplotlib first default color for plotting?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Matplotlib plots each column of my matrix `a` with 4 columns by blue, yellow, green, red.
[image]

Then, I plot only the second, third, fourth columns from matrix `a[:,1:4]`. Is it possible to make Matplotlib ignore blue from default and start from yellow (so my every lines get the same color as previous)?
[image]

```
a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(7,4), axis=0), axis=1)

lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a)
ax.legend(labels=lab )
# plt.show()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a[:,1:4])
ax.legend(labels=lab[1:4])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890412/increment-matplotlib-color-cycle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to skip the first color I would suggest getting a list of the current colors by using

```
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
```

As shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086276/get-default-line-colour-cycle) question/answer. Then set the color cycle for the current axes by using:

```
plt.gca().set_color_cycle()
```

Therefore your full example would be:

```
a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(7,4), axis=0), axis=1)

lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a)
ax.legend(labels=lab )

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
plt.gca().set_color_cycle(colors[1:4])
ax1.plot(a[:,1:4])
ax1.legend(labels=lab[1:4])
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The use of [`set_color_cycle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_color_cycle.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_color_cycle) is deprecated as of version 2.0. It should be replaced by [`set_prop_cycle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_prop_cycle.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_prop_cycle).

Answer (score 8):

The colors used for the successive lines are the one from a color cycler.
In order to skip a color in this color cycle, you may call

```
ax._get_lines.prop_cycler.next()  # python 2
next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)   # python 2 or 3
```

The complete example would look like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(7,4), axis=0), axis=1)
lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a)
ax.legend(labels=lab )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# skip first color
next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)
ax.plot(a[:,1:4])
ax.legend(labels=lab[1:4])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can insert an extra call to `ax.plot([],[])` before calling `ax.plot(a[:,1:4])`.

```
a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(7,4), axis=0), axis=1)

lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a)
ax.legend(labels=lab )
# plt.show()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([],[])
ax.plot(a[:,1:4])
ax.legend(labels=lab[1:4])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the impression that you want to make sure that every colone keeps a defined color. To do this you can create a color vector that matches each column to display. You can create a color vector. color = ["blue", "yellow", "green", "red"]

```
a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(7,4), axis=0), axis=1)

lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])
color = ["blue", "yellow", "green", "red"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a, color = color)
ax.legend(labels=lab )
# plt.show()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a[:,1:4])
ax.legend(labels=lab[1:4], color = color[1:4])
plt.show()
```