# Go to the next color of ax._get_lines.prop_cycler.next() continuously by loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I want to use the next color for each plot that I plot by `for` loop. But when I call `ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler.next()`, it cannot go to the third color. How to do something like `.next().next()` or `ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler.next()[k]` in the loop line by using `k in xrange()` ?

```
a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(7,4), axis=0), axis=1)

lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])

for k in xrange(4):
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 1), (k, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
    ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler.next()
    ax1.plot(a[:,k])
    plt.legend(labels=lab[k:k+1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code from the question, each subplot has its own colorcycle, such that `next` gives you the second color of the axes' colorcycle in each subplot.

A solution would be to share the same color cycle among all subplots.

For the case where you create the subplots inside the loop, you might use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(7,4), axis=0), axis=1)

lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])

for k in xrange(4):
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 1), (k, 0))
    if k==0:
        c = ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler
    else:
        ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler = c
    ax1.plot(a[:,k])
    plt.legend(labels=lab[k:k+1])

plt.show()
```

Or in a case where subplots are created all at once,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(7,4), axis=0), axis=1)

lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,1)
for k, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax._get_lines.prop_cycler = axes[0]._get_lines.prop_cycler
    ax.plot(a[:,k])
    ax.legend(labels=lab[k])

plt.show()
```

Of course you could also use the color cycler from each axes individually and propagate it to the next color

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(7,4), axis=0), axis=1)

lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,1)
for k, ax in enumerate(axes):
    for i in range(k):
        next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)
    ax.plot(a[:,k])
    ax.legend(labels=lab[k])

plt.show()
```

In all cases the result would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you create a new axes instance in every loop and then you do `ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler.next()`. Since `ax1` is a new object every time, you always get the same color.

The best solution is to explicitly pass the color to the plot. You should be able to obtain what you want with the following code, inspired by [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_default.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(7,4), axis=0), axis=1)
lab = np.array(["A","B","C","E"])

colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] 
colors = colors.by_key()['color']

for (k, label), color in zip(enumerate(lab), colors):
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 1), (k, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=4)
    ax1.plot(a[:,k], color=color)
    plt.legend(labels=label)

plt.show()
```

*Note*: my version of the code also avoids `xrange` and the `next()` method that fail in python3.

---

A warning: in your example, you use `ax1._get_lines`. Usually names starting with an underscore are considered private: therefore the matplotlib developers might change or remove the attribute `_get_lines` at any time without notice and break your code. I suggest you to make use of the public API as much as possible.

Comment: I think you meant to link to something with "this example"? Concerning `next` I updated [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672037/4124317) to include options for python 2 or 3 (`next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)`).

Comment: Thank you for spotting the missing link